# lazy initialization exception. как избавиться?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, lazyloading

Для доступа к данным использую JpaRepository. При Lazy загрузке вылетает lazyInitializationException. Прочитал, что можно пометить метод, где идет обращение @Transactional - но это не помогло

```
@Async
public void generate(int generateJobId){
    try {
        jobInfoService.setStatus(generateJobId,"IN_PROGRESS");
        List<Section> sections = sectionService.getAll();
        String filepath = helper.generateXlsx(sections, generateJobId);
        jobInfoService.setFilepath(generateJobId, filepath);
        jobInfoService.setStatus(generateJobId,"DONE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jobInfoService.setStatus(generateJobId,"ERROR");
    }
}
```

Репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface SectionRepository extends JpaRepository<Section, Long> {
    List<Section> findAllByGeologicalClasses_codeLikeIgnoreCase(String code);
}
```

В одном из методов идет обращение к связанным полям и вылетает исключение no Session. Как открыть сессию и загрузить данные?

```
@Transactional
int getMaxLength(List<Section> sections){
    Comparator<Section> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.getGeologicalClasses().size());
    Hibernate.initialize(sections);
    int maxSize = sections.stream().max(comparator).get().getGeologicalClasses().size();

    return maxSize;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Единственное, что пришло в голову это создать ещё один метод прогружающий данные

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Section> getAll(){
    return repository.findAll();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Section> getAllFullData(){
    List<Section> sections = repository.findAll();
    sections.forEach(section -> section.getGeologicalClasses().size());
    return sections;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял в этом случае нужно сразу понимать где понадобятся связанные данные и загружать их JOIN FETCH

```
@Repository
public interface SectionRepository extends JpaRepository<Section, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM section e JOIN FETCH e.geologicalClasses")
    List<Section> findAllFullData();

    List<Section> findAllByGeologicalClasses_codeLikeIgnoreCase(String code);
}
```